# What is the difference between „public static void Main()“ and „public static void Main(String[] args)“?

Tags: c#

Title says it.

When would I need to use

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
```

instead of

```
public static void Main()
```

Comment: You pass arguments for example when you call the program

Comment: When you want to use arguments provided by the method?

Comment: No *need*, you *may* specify args to get command line arguments.  Another way to get them is through Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().  Typically you'd use Main() for a Winforms/WPF app and Main(string[]) for a console mode app.  That's what the project templates do.  Also note that the return type can be *int*, equivalent to setting Environment.ExitCode.

Answer (score 0):

From geeksforgeeks
String []args: For accepting the zero-indexed command line arguments. args is the user-defined name. So you can change it by a valid identifer. [] must come before the args otherwise compiler will give errors.

Answer (score 0):

The variable args is an array of strings containing comman line arguments.

If you don't need to use them, you can not specify as a method parameter.

See "Main() and command-line arguments (C# Programming Guide)":

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/